# Swift: How can you declare an empty array of named tuples?

Tags: ios, swift

```
var test = [(face: SKNode, body: SKNode)]()
```

does not work. How can you declare an empty array of named tuples?

Answer (score 5):

You could always use a `typealias`

```
typealias MyTupleThing = (face: SKNode, body: SKNode)
var test = [MyTupleThing]()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var test: [(face: SKNode, body: SKNode)] = []
```

Or

```
var test = Array<(face: SKNode, body: SKNode)>()
```